# Cannot connect to GitHub from the command line or browser with a “server certificate verification failed” error

Tags: git, github, accessibility

For some strange reason I cannot figure out, GitHub has not been accessible from browser or terminal. I tried many solutions mainly from StackOverflow that says to re-install certificates. Those solutions did not work at all.

I’m located in India. The machine is inside a university network. All other machines in university network are able to access it, when I contacted them about this.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

The error from terminal when I clone is something like the following

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/somerepo.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

All other websites using HTTPS works well. Time is also set to current one.

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image: Image1 when I click on view certificate in Advanced option]
[image: Image2 when I click on view certificate in Advanced option]

Comment: Use the Advanced button to check the actual certificate what values are shown to you (certificate issuer and other data). May be there is an root CA config problem, may be you are behind an HTTPS intercepting proxy.

Comment: ``Someone could be trying to impersonate the site and you should not continue.
 
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust github.com because its certificate issuer is unknown, the certificate is self-signed, or the server is not sending the correct intermediate certificates.
 
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER``
This is what I see in advance option @Robert

Comment: There is a "Show certificate" label, klick it and add the screenshot to your post.

Comment: @Robert added screenshots to the question

Comment: What country are you in? I assume India based on the screenshots you have provided? This might be a geoblock based on the country your ISP is in.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm in India. The machine is inside a university network. All other machines in university network are able to access it, when I contacted them about this.

Comment: @Nagaraju Odd. What OS are you on?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Check the proxy settings, you are connected to the Internet through a Sophos anti-virus network traffic scanner. If there is not explicit proxy set on your system check the certificate info on other computers where it works if the certificate is also from Sophos CA.

Comment: @Robert Its not behind a proxy. I dont have access to other system. I got to know from the admin of the network there that they could access it

Answer (score 0):

### Seems like this might be connected to Internet censorship actions in India.

This error is really strange. And the screenshots you provide indicate you are located in India. It seems like [India has a history of censoring sites like GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_GitHub#India) and I am willing to bet that is the case here.

As that [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_GitHub#India) states:

> “India selectively censors websites at the federal and state levels. This is enforced by the Information Technology Act, 2000, as well as licensing requirements for Internet service providers (ISPs). Critics such as Rajeev Chandrasekhar have noted the vagueness of these regulations and the Centre for Internet and Society found that ISPs tended to over-comply with takedown requests.”

And this note about censorship actions in 2014:

> “On December 17, 2014, the Indian Department of Telecom issued an order to ISPs to block 32 websites. The notice was made public on December 31, 2014 and it included GitHub, GitHub's Gist, Vimeo, the Internet Archive, and various pastebin services.”

The only way around this might be to use a VPN. I would recommend testing this out by downloading and installing the [TOR Browser](https://www.torproject.org) and trying to connect GitHub through that.

Comment: Downloading tor browser also has error downloading. https://imgur.com/no6bJM1. I think in India its allowed as I have my personal computer with same OS I could access it

Comment: @Nagaraju Very strange. Hope this gets solved!